# How do I get info from lookup in salesforce query

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I have a custom salesforce object `Installation__c` and it has a custom field `Product__c` which is a lookup to a custom object `Product__c`  I am trying to get the fields from the child object using these query:

```
public with sharing class InstallationController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Installation__c> getItems() {
        // Perform isAccessible() checking first, then
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Installation_Display_Name__c, Product__c, Status__c, (SELECT Product__c.Name FROM Product__c)  FROM Installation__c];
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
Didn't understand relationship 'Product__c' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

I have tried changing the Query to
`FROM Product__r`and FROM `Product__c__r` but neither seems to work, how do I fix my query?

Comment: you need to go to the object that contains the look up and copy the `Child Relationship name` name after clicking on it with __r after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're traversing up or down a relationship hierarchy, the __c suffix becomes __r (r for 'relationship') until you finally get to the field that you're looking for (which still ends in __c if it's a custom field). So in your case, it will be

```
public with sharing class InstallationController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Installation__c> getItems() {
        // Perform isAccessible() checking first, then
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Installation_Display_Name__c, Product__r.Name, Status__c FROM Installation__c];
    }
}
```

So, the change here is, for the relationship you have to use **Product__r.Name**

Answer (score 0):

Click into the relationship on the object that has the look up. Copy the relationship name adding `__r` to it

This example would be `Test_Drives__r`

[image]